# 3d Matplotlib rectangle box, weather maps

Tags: matplotlib, 3d, shapes

I'm trying to create a weather map with 3d surface plot on Z-axis, along with an Earth map at the bottom.

The problem is, can't figure out how to make a rectangle or a different shape as a base. I prefer different domains to run weather models.

Matplotlib only allows the same shape of X, Y, Z.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

plt.show()
```

that example has 120,120 shapes of X, Y, Z. What I want is to make X shape (120,121) and Z shape (120,121) with the same Y shape.

I just want to make these kinds of maps on python, so I'm open to other library suggestions. I found some programs that run on windows, but I'd like to publish the maps so it's easy to make all maps from one program, python.

Also found that one; "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269014/contourf-in-3d-cartopy"

Comment: `ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')` is deprecated, use `ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')` instead

Comment: this also works, ax = plt.axes(projection="3d", xlim=[, ], ylim=[, ], zlim=[, ])